# how set this logo in extreme top left corner?

Tags: html, css, position

[screenshot top left corner crop photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YefZd.png)

**how to place this logo in extreme left corner with css or html so that it can be seen in white background**

i have tried many times changing position but nothing works , don't have much knowledge about css so please correct me what wrong i am doing in this and which code would do the job

*the current id is*

```
#mylogo {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

ps: i am just a beginner in html and css

Answer (score 0):

try adding px or % after the 0. For example:

Try this:

```css
#mylogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

or this:

```css
#mylogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing position from absolute to relative

```
#mylogo {
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative adds on to the original location. Absolute is the definite no-matter-what location. For relative, lets say you have a "position: relative; left: 120px;". The relative will add 120px to the original location of that element (in this case the logo).

Remember though, you HAVE to include px or % for the css to position it at all.

If you want the logo to at the top left corner of the visible window even as you scroll, use "position: fixed;"  For example:

```css
#mylogo {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it, put this in the CSS:

```
#mylogo {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
```

Then, it will stay at the top left of the screen.
For example, if you put this in the html:

```
<img id="mylogo" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/HqBAiwc9uD1sHBw2Uvac03pCXKE=/0x0:2012x1341/1400x1050/filters:focal(0x0:2012x1341):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/47070706/google2.0.0.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<style>body {height: 200px;}</style>
```

the google logo will stay at the top left of the screen.